# Get All Items in a Folder (including ALL subfolders)

Tags: 2010, folder

I am trying to get the count of the number of items in a SPFolder. I have tried several things so far however they seem to break once I add two subfolders. I want the total number of files in all folders contained within the top level folder (excluding folders as part of the total).

Example Folder Structure:

-Business Plans - 4 Files

--Archives - 1 File

---2012 - 1 File

What I have Tried (fldr = BusinessPlans in these scenarios):

```
    //Example A:
    SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
    query.Folder = fldr;
    SPListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
    int filecount = allitems.Count;

    //Example B:
    int filecount = fldr.Files.Count;

    //Example C:
    int filecount = fldr.ItemCount;
```

All seem to return filecount = 5

Any idea what I am doing wrong here or do I have to write a recursive function that total all the files up?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I added the recursive scope to the query and had success:

```
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Folder = fldr;

//Recursive Scope....
query.ViewAttributes = "Scope=\"Recursive\"";
SPListItemCollection allitems = list.GetItems(query);
int filecount = allitems.Count;
```

Are there any better solutions?

Answer (score 1):

try using SPFolder.ItemCount

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.itemcount(v=office.14).aspx

```
   using(SPSite site = new SPSite("site url"))
    {
      using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
      {
        SPFolder folder = web.GetFolder("/Docs/folder1");
        int count = folder.ItemCount;
      }
    }
```

Comment: If I am not mistaken this only worked for 1 subfolder, not multiple...